# Arduino Deputy function compute array

Tags: arduino

I use an Arduino Uno with Arduino IDE 1.8.3. I have two arrays. I want to write a Deputy function that can add two arrays, and return the result to the main function and print it.

But I want to use `x(sizeof(a))`, but it seems not correct...

How do I solve this problem?

This is my code:

```
int a[]={1,2,3,4,5,6},b[]={1,1,1,1,1,1};
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  int *p;
  p = add(a,b);
  for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
    Serial.print(*(p+i));
  }
}  

void loop() {
}

int * add(int *a,int *b) {
  int x = sizeof(a);
  int y = sizeof(b);
  static int z[4];
  for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
     z[i]=a[i]+b[i];
  }
  return z;
}
```

Comment: int x = sizeof(a); is equivalent to int x = 6; I think it should be something like int x[sizeof(a)];

Comment: I forgot to devide by the size of an element... so it could be something like x[sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])]

Answer (score 0):

`int* a` does not know the size of the array.
Easiest pass it as an extra parameter.

The next problem is that your static result cannot change its size dynamically.

`static` has additional problems anyway, in general.

```
int* add(const int *a,const int *b, int* result, byte size) {
  for(byte i=0; i<size; i++) {
     result[i]=a[i]+b[i];
  }
  return result;
}
```

Returning the result as the return value may be convenient.